# ScrollView in Dialog anchors to wrong place

Tags: android, dialog, scrollview

I have an alertdialog with a custom layout, including a scrollview.
When the dialog appears, the scrollview is "cropped", and appears to be anchored to the top of the Screen, rather than the top  of the dialog

I have searched SE for similar problems, and cannot find any.
Using a popup Window has exactly the same issue.
Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scroller"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/rock">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/scrollbutton"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="Room Number"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contents"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/scrollbutton"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="Here be Monsters" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And here is the dialog code:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contents, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialog.setView(layout);
    AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();
    alert.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    alert.show();
    Window window = alert.getWindow();
    window.setLayout((int)(screenWidth*.8), (int)(screenHeight*.8));
```

[image: ScrollView, as High as it will go]

I have tried adding the ScrollView as the root_view in the inflater, and also adding a LinearLayout around the ScrollView and setting this as root_view, but this does not alter the results

Answer (score 0):

You don't set parent to layout inflater. Let dialog manages view arranging [DialogFragment](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-dialogfragment)

Comment: I presume you mean this line:     View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contents, null);
   What would I replace "null" with?

Comment: When you implement your own DialogFragment you inflate your view in DialogFragment:: onCreateView method where you have inflater and parent container

Comment: Currently I am using AlertDialog, not DialogFragment. I have no onCreateView method.